# PHP Framework with great emphasis on AJAX/JavaScript integration (Raxan alternatives)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I'm planning to build a Web App that would do massive use of AJAX and JavaScript, and I want to use PHP as the Server-Side language, with MySQL for the DataBase.
I found Raxan, and it looked really good, mainly because it would save me a lot of time with it's very easy integration with jQuery and AJAX calls. However, the project do not seems very alive or stable, and the forum is almos desert.

So, I would like to know what is the best framework suitable for a Web App that will do everything in a single page through AJAX calls.

PS: If it matters, I will use jQuery Mobile, and that's why everything will be in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, there isn't much to "PHP + AJAX" integrations. It's the same as "PHP + HTML". I would recommend you find a good PHP framework and a good JavaScript framework instead of looking for one that does both because they are always a mess since they are built by people that don't understand separating concerns.

Comment: So, do you recomend me to use a framework like Yii, CodeIgniter, or so, and then do the JavaScrip/PHP by myself?

Comment: I recommend you start simple with something like CodeIgniter (PHP) and jQuery (JavaScript). Both have huge communities you can ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you having a look at Contao, but more information on what other features you want from a CMS are more important.

From the perspective of what you've described, Contao uses Mootools but can be mixed in with jQuery.
The core part of ajax queries is handled by an PHP executable in the root of the web server called ajax.php . This allows modules/widgets for FE or BE to communicate via AJAX calls and all nicely built in.

Don't worry about the Mootools part, since you could make a request using jQuery and it'll work seemsly with Contao and Mootools.